# Force displayed cells to be redraw

Tags: ui-grid

Within my cell templates I'm using single bind. It works normally, but when I remove a row from my grid I need that all cells that are being displayed to be destroyed and recreated, otherwise my grid gets "full of garbage from other rows".

Using two-way databind works normally, but the browser can't handle my grid. Using single-bind make the trick, everything that I'm using works, I'm just having problem to remove rows in runtime from the grid.

My guess is that the cells are being reused, and I'm using single-bind so the digest cycle is not updating the cells content as it was expected, so I would like to "force it" somehow

Comment: Try re rendering the entire grid,

Comment: @balajisoundar when you say rerender, you mean "$scope.gridApi.core.refresh();", it didn't work. I can't rerender the whole grid, I have too much data on it, it takes too much time to rerender (using ng-if)

Comment: `core.refresh` won't work as you're using one time binding. Have a ngIf on the grid container and when you want to update the grid. Simply set the ngIf flag to false and set it to true on a timeout . This will remove the grid from the ui and re render it with new data.

Comment: @balajisoundar but removing rerendering the whole grid is too much process consuming. I tried the ng-if in the grid container but the perfomace is terrible =/